# Implementation of Kendo Listview control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I was trying to implement Listview control of Kendo UI for MVC. I am trying to bind the list view with my model but I am getting this error :

"CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

I have checked some other questions on stackoverflow with the same error but I am unable to know the cause for this error as this is  kendo Syntax and there is nothing wrong with my code as far as I know.

The error is in this line::`.DataSource(ds => ds`

View Page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Courses";
}
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

<h2>Courses</h2>

<a href="/Home/Registration">Back</a>

<div class="bodywrap">
    <div class="CommonClass">

        @( Html.Kendo().ListView<K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel>(Model)
          .Name("listView")
          .TagName("div")
          .ClientTemplateId("template")
          .DataSource(ds => ds
          .Model(model =>
          {
              //The unique identifier (primary key) of the model is the ProductID property
              model.Id(p => p.ProductID);

              // Declare a model field and optionally specify its default value (used when a new model instance is created)
              model.Field(p => p.ProductName).DefaultValue("N/A");

              // Declare a model field and make it readonly
              model.Field(p => p.UnitPrice).Editable(false);
          })
)
    .Pageable()
         )
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/web/foods/")${ProductID}.jpg" alt="${ProductName} image" />
        <h3>${ProductName}</h3>
        <dl>
            <dt>Price:</dt>
            <dd>${kendo.toString(UnitPrice, "c")}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</script>

Model
namespace K_SampleProject.Models
{
    public class CourseModel
    {
        public List<tbl_Courses> CourseList { get; set; }
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
}

Controller
  public ActionResult Courses()
        {
            CourseModel Model = new CourseModel();
            RegistrationService ObjService = new RegistrationService();
            Model.CourseList = ObjService.GetCourses();
            return View(Model);
        }
```

Comment: Have you passed the model to this view? You should add: "@model K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel" and pass the model to this View unless you do it implicity from parent View.
Does the model that you pass has correct type (K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel)?

Comment: When I try to pass model to the view page, It gives compilation error
The best overloaded method match for 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory.ListView<K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I have updated my question with model and controller code also. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Is there an item of type `dynamic` lurking anywhere in your object model?

Comment: No. I have checked it again and there is not any.

Comment: I just passed my view model to view page as Ienumerable and it started working ::
@model IEnumerable<K_SampleProject.Models.CourseModel>
but it is still giving type errors.

Answer (score 0):

The main error in your code is that you passing single CourseModel class to the list, when it expects the List of CourseModel.
So, your Controller should looks like:

```
    public ActionResult Courses()
    {
        List<CourseModel> result;
        CourseModel Model = new CourseModel();
        RegistrationService ObjService = new RegistrationService();
        Model.CourseList = ObjService.GetCourses();
        result.Add(Model);
        return View(result);
    }
```

I also advise:

- Add `@model List<CourseModel>` in top of the View
- If it is a PartialView (not main view like index) change return for: `return PartialView(result);`